# jQuery Ajax fails when posting data due to keyword in post data

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

I know why the post fails, but I'm  not sure how to resolve it and I can't find any other references to this.  I'm taking our references to jEditable to make this simpler, as it happens without the jEditable plugin.

So how the heck do I "escape" the keyword so that it posts correctly?  Here's relevant code:

Test

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$(function() {
    $('#button').click(function() {
        $.ajax({
            type : 'POST',
            url : 'ajax/post_cms.php',
            dataType : 'html',
            data : {
                id : '1',
                data : '<p>This is a test of the system that shows me an alert !</p>'
            },
            success : function(data) {
                console.log(data);
            },
            error : function(XMLHttpRequest, textStatus, errorThrown) {
                console.log('An Ajax error was thrown.');
                console.log(XMLHttpRequest);
                console.log(textStatus);
                console.log(errorThrown);
            }
        });
    });
});
</script>

<input type="button" name="button" value="button" id="button" />
```

When it errors out, it's throwing the "error:" callback function, and the "errorThrown" is logged as undefined.  I'm positive it's the word "alert" because if I spell it "allert" in the one place it appears, everything posts just fine.  If you take out the HTML (so it's just "data : 'This is a test of the system that shows me an alert !'") it works just fine.

XMLHttpRequest =  "XMLHttpRequest readyState=4 status=0 multipart=false"
textStatus = "error"
errorThrown = "undefined"

GAH!!  HELP!!

Comment: BTW -- jEditable is found here: http://www.appelsiini.net/projects/jeditable

Comment: What is the textStatus of the error?

Comment: console.log(textStatus) just shows "error".  I took out the jEditable plug-in, and just posted some random data to a random page and if I include the work "alert" and the post data contains HTML (ie, "<p>alert</p>") then it bombs this same way.  So I'm sure it's not related to jEditable but rather to jQuery.  Unless I'm doing something wrong.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**UPDATE**:
The problem was a firewall catching the AJAX request as a XSS attack. If you're experiencing problems similar to those exhibited below, make sure to check your environment.

Symptoms:

1. Post data is failing with an error code of 0
2. Post data works in other places but not in your environment
3. Post data works as long as it doesn't contain any javascript functions
4. Your library doesn't seem like it should be at fault based on documentation
5. You can't find a bug in your library.

I think there's something else wrong here other than jQuery.
Your initial example works fine for me.

See a working example here: http://jsbin.com/ifami

*Note: I had to change your the ajax URL to a valid url but otherwise there were no other changes.*

That being said, you could try encoding your values as URI components:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$(function() {
        $('#button').click(function() {
                $.ajax({
                        type : 'POST',
                        url : 'ajax/post_cms.php',
                        dataType : 'html',
                        data : {
                                id : '1',
                                data : encodeURIComponent('<p>This is a test of the system that shows me an alert !</p>')
                        },
                        success : function(data) {
                                console.log(data);
                        },
                        error : function(XMLHttpRequest, textStatus, errorThrown) {
                                console.log('An Ajax error was thrown.');
                                console.log(XMLHttpRequest);
                                console.log(textStatus);
                                console.log(errorThrown);
                        }
                });
        });
});
</script>
```

Comment: What the heck is it then?  I'm lost.  I changed the URL from the relative path to an absolute path -- no change.  I downloaded the latest jQuery library (1.3.2) to ensure I was using that.  Headers look the same when I inspect them.  Server configuration then?

Comment: But if I take my example above and spell "alert" as "allert" it works just fine ......

Comment: Does the ajax call support GET? If so, can you try visiting the page manually to see what he output is? Maybe it isn't the input but the output that is causing the error?

Comment: What is the value of XMLHttpRequest.responseText? What is the server actually trying to return?

Comment: @coderjoe: The post_cms.php scripts only has one line: print_r($_POST)

The XMLHttpRequest.responseText isn't a valid property.  The console dumps what's present in Firebug are at the bottom of the question.

Comment: @coderjoe: I'm sorry, I looked in the wrong place.  XMLHttpRequest.reponseText is null ("").

Comment: Have you tried encoding your post data as a URI component? (see the above change to my answer)

Comment: @coderjoe: I just added the encodeURIComponent() function, and I get the same result.  But, I copy and paste my exact code to JSBin and it works just fine.  ARGH!

Comment: oh, I forgot to mention, try converting your AJAX url to be a full path including http://

Comment: @coderjoe: Did that, still fails, same error.  But again -- misspell "alert" and it works.

Comment: Try changing the return type to "text". I doubt print_r returns valid HTML.

Comment: @coderjoe: I've tried 'text' and 'json' and neither work.  But it's not even getting a response from the server.  Firebug doesn't show any response, just the Headers being sent.

Comment: Also what do the headers being sent look like? Do they look valid? Check your http access and error logs, are there any hints there as to why there is no response from the server? Is it reaching the server? Is there an error you're not seeing?

Comment: Just to confirm, the php file and the website containing the javascript/html are the same server right? You're not executing this locally right?

Comment: @coderjoe: Here's what I'm seeing on my end (note, the website is not publicly accessible): http://nloding.com/ajax_error_headers.png, http://nloding.com/ajax_error_post.png.  These were taken before the encodeURIComponent, but the same errors are generated, just different post data as it's encoded.  Nothing in the error.log or access.log files in Apache -- shows test.php being pulled but nothing for the post_cms.php page.  It's not even hitting that page.

Comment: Is the test.php file globally accessable? Could I give it a try myself?

Comment: @coderjoe: Unfortunately it is not, as this is a secure website with sensitive data.  The site is locked down for only internal use.  The exact contents of test.php are posted, above though, and post_cms.php only has print_r($_POST) at this point.

Comment: I'm not going to lie, I'm completely out of answers and have been for a while. I suggest making sure that you experience the same errors in both IE and Firefox to rule out any bugs browser side. Then I'd suggest making sure it isn't your secure website denying the connection before it even happens or something equally crazy.
Best of luck!

Comment: I have a theory. Alter your script so instead of spitting out POST it spits out GET. Then point your browser to the url with the query string at the end. Something like: "http://your.server/ajax/post_cms.php?id=1&data=<p>This%20is%20a%20test%20of%20the%20system%20that%20shows%20me%20an%20alert%20</p>". If it doesn't work make sure to check with your systems administrator to make sure that they aren't running some sort of Intrusion Detection System which might be actively denying your request because it thinks it is an XSS attack?

Comment: @coderjoe: Well, you were right, a firewall was grabbing it as XSS.  But only during an asynchronous request, which is why it was only that Ajax function that failed.  Because I could post other items containing the word 'alert,' I totally didn't think of it as a firewall issue.  THANKS A MILLION!!

Comment: Glad I could help. You can thank my friend Occam and his ever sharp razor for leading me to that final conclusion. :P I'm going to update my question with the discovered solution so people with similar problems might find it sooner.

Comment: And to finish describing the solution -- our firewalls were grabbing asynchronous requests as dangerous, and then scanning them for keywords, just as 'alert,' 'replace,' 'object,' and 'eval' -- but they were only looking for the words, not the function (ie, not 'alert(' or something).  So it was killing my GET/POST request.

Answer (score 0):

If it's only the word alert, you could simply change it to something else, like #1234# and then parse it back. It's hacky but a library that crash if you enter "alert" sounds pretty funky to me.

You could also go in the lib code and fix it... or open a ticket and get them to fix it. It sounds to me it's a pretty important issue!

Answer (score 0):

I think maybe your data: parameter needs another set of parenthesis, like so:

```
 data : ({ id : '1',
           data : '<p>This is a test of the system that shows me an alert !</p>'
           }),
```

Comment: @Neil: That was a fantastic idea -- but nope!  I tried that with and without the encodeURIComponent and it still fails on my server.  But again, only if the word "alert" is present.